# How to install Pygame in Python

Tags: python, pygame

I'm a student learning Python and we have a project that needs to reference Pygame.  I have no idea how to get this to work on my home computer. 
I'm using Python 3.7 (64 bit) on Windows 10 Home.

Thank you for any direction. 
Matt

Comment: Take a look at the get started page https://www.pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted

Comment: Do you have pip3 installed? The pygame documentation says to run `python3 -m pip install -U pygame --user`

Comment: Thanks.  Where would I type that exactly.  I just can't seem to figure it out.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Matt have you tried installing it with pip:

```
pip3 install pygame
```

For user based installs, check out:

https://www.pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted

pip3 install's make it easy to import

Comment: Thank you.  I honestly don't even know where to type "pip3 install pygame"  where exactly would I do that?  I warned you, i'm a complete newbie. Thanks again.

Comment: are you using linux or osx? It would be in the terminal in osx under utilities. In linux, it's under the program terminal

Comment: Im just using a windows laptop.  Windows 10 Home

Comment: I can't just type it at C:\  can I?

Comment: You can if you install it with these guidelines; https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/install-pip-windows/

Comment: where would the 'ideal' place to type this.  It's telling me I don't even have pip or pip3 installed but I'm sure it's because I'm not typing it in the correct directory

Comment: Type it in in the same directory where `pip` is  — probably something like `C:\Python3\Scripts`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick guide to help you install Pygame: http://kidscancode.org/blog/2015/09/pygame_install/

pip is a command that should work for you since you have Python 3.7 installed already.

Comment: Thank you.  Could you tell me exactly where I would type the command?  I don't actually know. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame) and download the appropriate installer for your computer.
2. pip install your_download_file.whl

pls, try it.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm really not sure where to type that command.  Can you guide me - I'm really new to this.